# Qt QNetworkReply connection closed

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

I try to execute post method in c++ to a url `https://...`, but I receive connection closed error.

I see that my code works if I use another url like `https://www.google.gr`.

If I remove the port `8181`  I get error: `server replied:not found`.

My code is

```
static const char *REQUEST_URL="https://...";
static const char *USER = "....";
static const char *PASSWORD = "....";

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    finishedexecuted=0;
    QByteArray postData;
    postData.append("username=...");
    postData.append("password= ...");
    m_network = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    QUrl url=QUrl(REQUEST_URL);
    request.setUrl(url);
    QSslConfiguration config = request.sslConfiguration();        
    QList<QSslCertificate> certs = 
                          QSslCertificate::fromPath("pistopoiitiko.crt");
    config.setCaCertificates(certs);        
    request.setSslConfiguration(config);
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_network->post(request,postData);

    downloadTime.start();
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),
                     SLOT(slotSetProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    QObject::connect(m_network, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
                     SLOT(slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

    connect(m_network, 
            SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)),
            this, 
            SLOT(sslError(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> &)));
    } 

void MainWindow::sslError(QNetworkReply* reply, 
                           const QList<QSslError> &errors )
{...}

void MainWindow::slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
 ...
    if (reply->error() > 0) {
    m_label->setText("Error number = " + reply->errorString());
   }
 ...
}

void MainWindow::slotSetProgress(qint64 received, qint64 total)
{...}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Put some debug print statements in for sslError and see if it's firing the sslError signal. If it is that'll narrow it down for you.

Answer (score 1):

i achieved to overcome this problem with this code

```
QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
config.setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);
```

then i received ssl errors that i passed with ignoresslerrors()