# Error opening url <u_r_l>: SSL handshake failed

Tags: ssl, phantomjs

I m using `phantomJS` `v2.0.0.`

Trying to open this page:
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ ' without success, getting this error:

```
Error opening url "https://play.google.com/apps/publish/": SSL handshake failed
```

I've tried so far this actions:

1. Add flag `--ssl-protocol=TLSv1`
2. Add flag `--ssl-protocol=any`
3. Add flag `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes`
4. Change the `user-agent`

Nothing solve the error.

Any help/suggestions?

My code looks like this:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    page.reason = resourceError.errorString;
    page.reason_url = resourceError.url;
};


page.open(
    "https://play.google.com/apps/publish/",
    function (status) {
        if ( status !== 'success' ) {
            console.log(
                "Error opening url \"" + page.reason_url
                + "\": " + page.reason
            );
            phantom.exit( 1 );
        } else {
            console.log( "Successful page open!" );
            phantom.exit( 0 );
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473169/phantomjs-certain-pages-failing-to-open