# Issue trying to use PhantomJS to process a web page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to make a crawler for SEO purposes, and I can't seem to get PhantomJS to at least download this particular page: https://tablet.euroslots.com/home/

If I use cURL it works fine (but obviously doesn't process the javascript):

```
✓ 1344:0 /cherrytech/js-crawler root› curl https://tablet.euroslots.com/home/
<!doctype html><!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> ...
```

My PhantomJS script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response));
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A406 Safari/8536.25';
page.open('https://tablet.euroslots.com/home/', function() {
  console.log(page.content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

And this is the result of running it:

```
✓ 1347:0 /cherrytech/js-crawler root› phantomjs crawler.js
Request {
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A406 Safari/8536.25"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "method": "GET",
    "time": "2014-09-16T16:02:24.426Z",
    "url": "https://tablet.euroslots.com/home/"
}
Unable to load resource (#1URL:https://tablet.euroslots.com/home/)
Error code: 2. Description: Connection closed
Response (#1, stage "end"): {"contentType":null,"headers":[],"id":1,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"end","status":null,"statusText":null,"time":"2014-09-16T16:02:24.763Z","url":"https://tablet.euroslots.com/home/"}
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: You can also register to `onResourceError`. You will see that the connection is closed. I don't know why. `--web-security=false` and `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` does nothing. You can also try [slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org/) instead of phantomjs. Maybe it is a phantomjs limitation

Comment: I've tried CasperJS and it does the same thing. ):

Comment: I've just updated the code to register to `onResourceError`

Comment: Try to upgrade Phantomjs eg 1.9.8

Answer (score 5):

Try calling phantomjs with --ssl-protocol=any

I had the same exact problem, with an external site that worked one week ago.

So I searched, and found a related issue described at [Qt QNetworkReply connection closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063824/qt-qnetworkreply-connection-closed). It helped me look into the phantomjs' embedded Qt: it defaults to forcing new connections in SSLv3, which is either too new for old sites, or too old for new sites (but was quite a reasonable default at the time Qt 4.8.4 was released).

With "any", you tell phantomjs to try all protocols, which should help you pass the test. It will try more-secure-than-SSLv3 protocols, but less-secure-than-SSLv3 too (SSLv3 is at middle range). So, if "any" works, you should then try to force a more-secure-than-SSLv3 value instead of letting "any". In my case, specifying --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 worked.

Guess that the recent issues with SSL (goto fail, heartbleed, poodle, and so on) made a whole lot of websites upgrade their servers, now refusing SSLv3 connections.
But in case your server uses an older-than-SSLv3 protocol, keep the "any" (and all the security risks associated…).

Comment: This should probably be 'the' answer. SSLv3 is a bad default since heartbleed!